# Navigation controller view offsetting on status bar hide on iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationcontroller

Weird `iOS 7` issue I am having.

I have a `UINavigationController` added as a `child view controller` to my `main view controller`.

When I hide the status bar (by setting `preferredStatusBarHidden` and calling `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate`), the navigation controllers top view controller recesses the 20 pixels that the status bar did, but not the `UINavigationBar`. This is only happening on `iOS 7` - and I cannotfind a work around. If I rotate the device, it corrects the issue?

**Before I hide the status bar**

[image: before hide status bar]

**After I hide the status bar**

[image: after hide status bar]

I have tried calling `layoutIfNeeded` and `updateViewConstraints`. These did nothing. Was able to do conditional checks for version number and add constraints to fix, but this breaks things worse on rotate and I would prefer a cleaner solution if anyone has any ideas.

Thanks.